# Language issues with APA/biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have the following bib. entry:

```
@InBook{CO2008,
  author    = {F. Courchesne and M. C. Turmel},
  editor    = {M. R. Carter and E. G. Gregorich},
  pages     = {p. 307--316},
  publisher = {Boca Raton: CRC Press},
  title     = {Extractable {A}l, {F}e, {M}n, and {S}i},
  year      = {2008},
  address   = {Boca Raton},
  edition   = {2nd ed.},
  booktitle = {Soil {S}ampling and methods of analysis},
}
```

When I use the biblatex package and the APA sytle and the brazilian option for the babel package I get the following:

**REFERENCES**
Courchesne, F. & Turmel, M. C. (2008). Extractable Al, Fe, Mn, and Si. **Em** M. R. Carter
& E. G. Gregorich (**Ed.**), Soil Sampling and methods of analysis (2nd ed., p. 307–316).
Boca Raton: CRC Press.

How can I get **In** instead of **Em** (portuguese word) and **Eds.** instead of **Ed.**

Thank you!

Comment: If you pass (only) the `brazilian` option to the `babel` package (or it is the last/main option), your main document language is Brazilian. `biblatex` will adapt to that and will also try to produce a Brazilian bibliography. It would normally look odd to have an English bibliography in a Brazilian text. Do you want an all-English document or an all-Brazilian document?

Comment: Thanks moewe! Good question. Indeed the text is written in Portuguese but here in Brazil the standard is to use In instead Em. When I set up babel to English I get In and Eds. However, the citations with et al. appear wrong all over the text.

Comment: Actually, If I use: \usepackage[brazilian, USenglish]{babel} I get what I want; for instance: Leinweber, P., Hagemann, P., Kebelmann, L., Kebelmann, K., & Morshedizad, M. (2019).
Bone char as a novel phosphorus fertilizer. In H. Ohtake & S. Tsuneda (Eds.), Phos-
phorus recovery and recycling (p. 419–432). Singapore: Springer.

Comment: However, the citations become, for instance, Lopes and Melo and I need Lopes e Melo or Lopes & Melo.  Obs. e means and in Portuguese. Any way to do that?

Comment: Do you want your bibliography entries to be completely in English or just to change the two words mentioned in your question? (Suppose for the moment there are more words that `biblatex` can typeset for you in the bibliography.)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{brazil}{%
    in = {In:},%
editor = {ed.},
editors = {eds.},
byeditor = {editado por},
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: De nada. If it was useful, please accept the answer as correct.